After setup nativewind does not work with expo
Update: tailwind started working, I have no clue why it just started working without changing anything in the code base. The only difference was that I switched to a different phone to pixel 4 in Android Studio when testing, but I do not think this is the cause.
Original question:
I followed every step in the documentation for the setup, but still cannot get nativewind to work
https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo (documentation link)





I also had the same issue following the Nativewind + Expo docs. The example project is now two years out of date and uses Expo v46 (v51 is current).
Then I found this starter repo which has v51 working with Nativewind v4. I updated my project's dependencies to suit, and I also copied some changes from metro.config.js and tailwind.config.js into my project. It's now working.
Hope this helps someone.

that worked for me too, the problem is on babel.config.js, using the example from the repo does the trick. Thank you

I had the same problem.
I followed the documentation and set everything correctly, but styles were not applied. Hours after crawling on the internet I found a simple solution, which is "clear the cache".
expo start -c

for more details, check nativewind docs

Your problem probably is in your tailwind.config.js. This line:
content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],

The file app/index.js that you are trying to use is not included. All the files (or folders) that you are planning to use with library should be listed there.
Try updating that line to this:
content: ["app/index.js", "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],

In this line, we added the index.js file.
More info, check the docs.

Sadly it did not work, but thanks for the answer

@dkorsakas try adding import "./styles.css"; in your index.js before export default function Home() {

this is not necessary as far as I know, it is not specified in the docs and also in this youtube tutorial the person did not add styles.css and it worked fine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AehQRLkVkiE&ab_channel=CodeWithRomaen

@dkorsakas I've just suggested that because I was looking at the expo example https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/blob/next/examples/expo/App.tsx and then I saw that import in the tsx file

it is rather weird, but it just started working today, I did not change any code - it just started working - I have no clue why

@dkorsakas oh, that's weird indeed. Anyways, I'm happy your code is working now :).

Ok, for expo sdk >=50, follow this link https://www.nativewind.dev/v4/getting-started/expo-router
after setting up,
create an index.js file in the root of your folder and add the following lines of code:
import "./global.css"; 
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import { ExpoRoot } from "expo-router";
export function App() {
 const ctx = require.context("./app");
 return <ExpoRoot context={ctx} />;
}
registerRootComponent(App);

Then go to your package.json file and change the main field to point to index.js i.e
"main":"index.js"
Let me know if this helps.

Thanks for the instructions, but the additional index.js file and the change in package.json were not necessary. I just followed the steps from the link you provided with the v4 docs https://www.nativewind.dev/v4/getting-started/expo-router. The crucial step was resetting the cache with npx expo start -c, which is mentioned in the troubleshooting guide on the NativeWind page https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/troubleshooting. Everything is working perfectly now.

This is not working because it is not compatible with the nativewind package in package.json

use command DEBUG=nativewind npx expo start -c  instead of npx
expo start -c
I found a problem that react-native-safe-area-context@4.14.0 - expected version: 4.12.0 Your project may not work correctly until you install the expected versions of the packages.
After running the command npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.12.0 and npx
expo start -c tailwind is working fine on both mobile and web

